# counting the number of squares in a bipartite networkx graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have a bipartite network and I would like to count the number of squares in the network, for instance:

```
import networkx as nx
B=nx.Graph()
B=nx.bipartite.random_graph(100, 100, .05)
```

I know that networkx has a built in method to calculate square clustering coefficient (the share of closed 4-paths vs open 3-paths), but I would like to simply count the number of closed 4 paths. Can someone think of a nice trick using built in functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply adjust the code [`nx.square_clustering`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.square_clustering.html), as follows. If needed wrap it into a function

```
v = 0 # or any other node
clustering = 0
potential = 0
for u, w in combinations(B[v], 2):
    squares = len((set(B[u]) & set(B[w])) - {v})
    clustering += squares
```